What drivers do I need to install for an Epson in Kubuntu?
I have an Epson XP-235 and I want to use it with a Kubuntu 22.04
I tried to find the drivers and from the Epson FAQ I found the following page:
https://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/
There I searched XP-235 and Linux and I got the following results

I think I need to install the first one 1.8.5 and the scanner (last row).
But what is the Epson Printer Utility in the second row? Do I need that to make the printer function properly?

How is the printer connecting to the computer? Have you just tried connecting it and seen what happens? Have you looked through that site for information what that utility is? Have you just tried installing the drivers and seen what happened? This is something that will be quite easy to test. Please test it and let us know the outcome.

At a guess, the "Utility" does things such as checking ink level. It does no harm to install, the other two and test functionality, so try it. If there are scanning or printing issues, install the utlity.

I would suggest to install first the driver and test well. Only if the printer works to try installing the scanner (and uninstall if it causes a problem or is useless).

@music2myear: I have connected it with a cable and I can see it reported but it does not work. I see a list of Epson printers available but I don't know which one to choose so I found those I mention in the post

The driver you need to install, for all Debian/Ubuntu and derivatives is the first one in your screenshot. After following the link and accepting the license you should arrive at:
https://support.epson.net/linux/Printer/LSB_distribution_pages/en/escpr.php
where you should download the deb package and install it the usual way(s).
Reboot and test.
If everything is working, repeat the process to install the (optional) scanner software, Epson Scan 2. It should work the same with any generic software anyway. If you want to use the scanner via WiFi then make sure you also have installed the sane-airscan package.

I installed the same file from the URL in my post. It is the exact file as in your post. I installed it and did not work. Then I noticed you mention "Reboot". Then after reboot, it worked. I didn't expect that reboot would be required! How come?

Where can I get sane-airscan? Do I need anything extra to print over wifi?

It should be in the official repositories and typically already installed. This is only for remote scanning, nothing else is necessary for printing.

@Jim If the answer was useful then please accept it.
